# Convert a list to dictionary - Ansible YAML

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible, yaml, jinja2

I have a playbook, where I get an error message

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"tasks": {}}, "ansible_included_var_files": [], "changed": false, "message": "/home/user/invoke_api/automation/tmp/task.yml must be stored as a dictionary/hash"}
```

**task.yml**

The file **task.yml** is dynamically created, and filtered all the time from another source to give the output below.

```
-   key: gTest101
    value:
        Comments: FWP - Testing this
        IP: 10.1.2.3
        Name: gTest101
-   key: gTest102
    value:
        Comments: FWP - Applying this
        IP: 10.1.2.4
        Name: gTest102
```

**Question**: How do I convert the list in my task.yml to a dictionary? What's the code to convert from list to dictionary

**playbook.yml**

```
---
- name: Global Objects
  hosts: check_point
  connection: httpapi
  gather_facts: False
  vars_files:
    - 'credentials/my_var.yml'
    - 'credentials/login.yml'
  tasks:
  - name: read-new-tmp-file
    include_vars:
      file: tmp/task.yml
      name: tasks
    register: new_host

  - name: add-host-object-to-group
    check_point.mgmt.cp_mgmt_host:
      name: "{{ item.value.Name | quote }}"          
      ip_address: "{{ item.value.IP | quote }}"      
      comments: "{{ item.value.Comments }}"
      groups: gTest1A
      state: present
      auto_publish_session: yes
    loop: "{{ new_host.dict | dict2items }}"  
    delegate_to: Global
    ignore_errors: yes
```

Ansible core 2.9.13
python version = 2.7.17

Comment: what's your play content? Is your task.yaml a var files or an ansible tasks file ? what's your playbook core ? ansible version ? how can we reproduct the bug to help you?

Comment: @idrissEliguene I have updated the playbook. Ansible core 2.9.13
python version = 2.7.17

Comment: @idrissEliguene 

this is the task.yml. it is dynamically created , I can't add any variable to the file "task.yml"
```-   key: gTest101
    value:
        Comments: FWP - Testing this
        IP: 10.1.2.3
        Name: gTest101
-   key: gTest102
    value:
        Comments: FWP - Applying this
        IP: 10.1.2.4
        Name: gTest102
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: *"**How do I convert the list in my task.yml to a dictionary?**"*

A: Use [items2dict](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-lists-into-dictionaries). For example, read the file and create the list

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        l1: "{{ lookup('file', 'task.yml')|from_yaml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
    l1:
      - key: gTest101
        value:
          Comments: FWP - Testing this
          IP: 10.1.2.3
          Name: gTest101
      - key: gTest102
        value:
          Comments: FWP - Applying this
          IP: 10.1.2.4
          Name: gTest102
```

Then, the task below

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        d1: "{{ l1|items2dict }}"
```

creates the dictionary

```yaml
  d1:
    gTest101:
      Comments: FWP - Testing this
      IP: 10.1.2.3
      Name: gTest101
    gTest102:
      Comments: FWP - Applying this
      IP: 10.1.2.4
      Name: gTest102
```

Answer (score 1):

A vars file is a yaml dict file, so your list have to be a fields of a vars:

```html
my_vars:
  - Comments: FWP - Testing this
    IP: 10.1.2.3
    Name: gTest101
  - Comments: FWP - Applying this
    IP: 10.1.2.4
    Name: gTest102
```

and you dont need to register the include_vars tasks. Just loop on the list var name (here my_vars).

```html
---
- name: Global Objects
  hosts: check_point
  connection: httpapi
  gather_facts: False
  vars_files:
    - 'credentials/my_var.yml'
    - 'credentials/login.yml'
  tasks:
  - name: read-new-tmp-file
    include_vars:
      file: tmp/task.yml

  - name: add-host-object-to-group
    check_point.mgmt.cp_mgmt_host:
      name: "{{ item.Name }}"          
      ip_address: "{{ item.IP }}"      
      comments: "{{ item.Comments }}"
      groups: gTest1A
      state: present
      auto_publish_session: yes
    loop: "{{ my_vars }}"  
    delegate_to: Global
    ignore_errors: yes
```

Comment: this is the task.yml file. it is dynamically created (I have updated the file)

```
-   key: gTest101
    value:
        Comments: FWP - Testing this
        IP: 10.1.2.3
        Name: gTest101
-   key: gTest102
    value:
        Comments: FWP - Applying this
        IP: 10.1.2.4
        Name: gTest102
```